# Set theory operations proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Demonstrate that $A \cap (B \cup C) = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C)$

How can I proof that?
Well, if I pick up an $ x \in A$ and the same $ x \in B \cup C$, then $x \in (A \cap (B \cup C))$.

If $ x \in A $, and if $x \in B$ and $x \notin C$, then the equality is true. Or, $ x \in A $, and if $x \notin B$ and $x \in C$, then the equality is true. For last, $ x \in A $, and if $x \in B$ and $x \in C$, then the equality is true again.

Is this enough to proof the equality?

Comment: It's not really accurate to say that the "equality is true" when dealing with cases of individual members $x$ of the sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's basically correct, but it can be slightly simplified and clarified.

For the clarification, you should note that if $x \in B \cup C$ then it must be true that either $x \in B$ or $x \in C$. You haven't explicitly stated that, but you have used that fact.

For the simplification, you don't have to consider the three cases: (1) $x \in B$ and $x \notin C$, (2) $x \in C$ and $x \notin B$, and (3) $x \in B$ and $x \in C$. It is enough to just consider two cases: (1) $x \in B$ (and we don't care whether $x$ is in $C$ or not), and (2) $x \in C$ (and we don't care whether $x$ is in $B$ or not).